# construct a class chosen by index from a list of classes, c++

Tags: c++

I'm looking for a solution to this problem:
I have a parent class `MyParent` and a couple of child classes that inherit from `MyParent`. I want to be able to construct a selected class according to an index. For example say I have 4 child classes that are somehow in a list called classesList, I want to be able to call `classesList[2]();` where 2 is the index of the selected class.

I'm wondering how to make this list, what type should it have? I don't want the class to be actually initialized in the list, I just want a reference to the constructor so that it's constructed only when I choose an index from the list.

Comment: A switch statement based on id in the array to allocate the correct type? Not sure what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

You could have a list of function pointers:

```
struct Base { virtual ~Base() {} };

struct X1 : Base { /* ... */ };
struct X2 : Base { /* ... */ };
struct X3 : Base { /* ... */ };
// ...

std::unique_ptr<Base> makeX1() { return std::unique_ptr<Base>(new X1); }
std::unique_ptr<Base> makeX2() { return std::unique_ptr<Base>(new X2); }
std::unique_ptr<Base> makeX3() { return std::unique_ptr<Base>(new X3); }
// ...

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>(*)()> makers = { makeX1, makeX2, makeX3 };
```

Usage:

```
void f(std::size_t class_index)
{
    auto p = makers[class_index]();
    // use p
}
```